# GLSL simple colour function causes error

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, gpu

I have copied HSV2RGB colour function exactly from a working code into another code on the shadertoy website, and it says-

```
  no matching overloaded function found, 
  cannot convert from "constant mediump float" to "3 vector component of float"
```

this is the function that refuses to work:

```
 vec3 hsv2rgb(vec3 c)//<---crashes
 {
  vec4 K = vec4(1.0, 2.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 3.0);
  vec3 p = abs(fract(c.xxx + K.xyz) * 6.0 - K.www);
  return c.z * mix(K.xxx, clamp(p - K.xxx, 0.0, 1.0), c.y);
 }
```

here is an example glsl sandbox with the error, https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MsS3Rh it's in lines 24 to 33.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual error is in part of the code you ***did not*** include in your question text:

```
void main(void)
{
    vec3 HSV = hsv2rgb(.1,.2,.3);
                       ~~~~~~~~ BAD!
    ...
```

To fix this, use:

```
vec3 HSV = hsv2rgb (vec3 (.1, .2, .3));
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your fix, same thing. here is the error, using the shadertoy web page. thanks!  https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MsS3Rh it's in line 24 to 33

Comment: I'm sorry i Reeely did attempt that solution at some stage when the function was written abit differently/at end of page, i thought i had tried it 2 times at least. Thanks so much!!!